# How to get rid of View State completely in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

How can I get rid of:

```
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="..."/>
```

Completely !

Comment: It's obvious that you want to get rid of viewstate altogether but, if you wanted just to optimise it, rather than turning it off, you might find my answer to another question helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3865762/205245

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to add the EnableViewState="false" to the @Page directive in the Default.aspx file.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
Codebehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Sample._Default"
EnableViewState="false" %>
```

Then, add the following code to the Default.aspx.cs file. This removes the hidden field from the generated HTML.

```
    #region Disable ViewState
    protected override void SavePageStateToPersistenceMedium(object state)
    {
    }
    protected override object LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium()
    {
        return null;
    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: As answered below, it is easier to disable view state on the web.config level (or even machine.config level). <pages enableViewState="false"/>

Comment: I wonder why that does not work for me. Still have ViewState in the GET requests.

Comment: I did that and viewstate is still there. Any element that has `runat=server` also has viewstate disabled, viewstate is disabled in `web.config`, but the damn thing still there!

Answer (score 5):

At the control level, EnableViewState="false".

At the page level, EnableViewState=false in the Page directive.

At the applicaiton level add this to .config, < pages enableViewState="false" >

Comment: Implemented all that and still having ViewState.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can disable it in machine.config :

< Pages enableViewState="false"/>

That should disable viewstate for all pages.

Answer (score 1):

```
#region Disable ViewState
protected override void SavePageStateToPersistenceMedium(object state)
{
}
protected override object LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium()
{
    return null;
}
#endregion
```

This is awesome.However, just to let everyone know it's still rendering an empty viewstate hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="" />
```

Comment: I'd be better if you added this as a comment, not as an answer.